# How to use OR operator with DynamoDB KeyConditionExpression

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

DynamoDB table has three data rows all with the same `PK` value but different `SK`:

Row 1: `PK: PROJECT` `SK: A-001`

Row 2: `PK: PROJECT` `SK: B-001`

Row 3: `PK: PROJECT` `SK: C-001`

I want to make query that returns only two rows with SK that start with "A" and "C".

First I define it for the item with SK that begins with "A" and it works:

```
    resp = dynamodb.query(
        TableName='my-table',
        KeyConditionExpression="PK = :pk AND (begins_with(SK, :those_with_A) ),
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":pk": { "S": "PROJECT" },
            ":those_with_A": { "S": "A" }
        }
    )
```

Next I add `OR` operator to query `SK` that begins with "C":

```
    resp = dynamodb.query(
        TableName='my-table',
        KeyConditionExpression="PK = :pk AND (begins_with(SK, :those_with_A) OR  begins_with(SK, :those_with_C) ),
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":pk": { "S": "PROJECT" },
            ":those_with_A": { "S": "A" },
            ":those_with_C": { "S": "C" },
        }
    )
```

Unfortunately it fails with error

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: OR
```

How to correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have OR as a condition in your `Keyconditionexpression`

> For KeyConditions, only the following comparison operators are supported:
> EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN

You need to make two individual Query requests to suit your needs.

You can achieve this in a single request using PartiQL ExecuteStatement API using SQL like syntax:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html